# Doctrine - many to one; Populating many, can't use the constant "ones" on the DB. How to insert manually the FKs?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the following model:

```
    class Word{

          ...........
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Language", cascade={"persist"})
 * @JoinColumn(name="language_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */

protected $language;

   ..........................    

}

     class Language{
/**
 * @Id
 * @Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @Column(type="string", unique=true, nullable=false)
 */
protected $language;

 ........
}
```

I have 3 records in the database for 3 different languages. A language is unique.

I fail to create a new word and link it to one of the existing languages. I.e. I would like to know how to set the FK of Word to the PK of the language. And since FKs in the model don't exists as int IDs but rather object references, I am confused on how to implement it. I tried to use a Doctrine_Query::create()-> ... but I also failed with that.

I have tried this:

```
    $this->em = $this->doctrine->em;

    $w = $this->input->post('word');
    $d = $this->input->post('description');

    $desclan = $this->input->post('desclan'); //language is selected from a drop down 
                                              //list populated from the DB 
    $wordlan = $this->input->post('wordlan');

        $word = new Entity\Word;
        $description = new Entity\Description;
        $language = new Entity\Language;

        $language->setLanguage($wordlan);
        $language->setLanguageId($lanId); // assuming that $lanId is obtained from DB


        $word->setWord($w);
        $word->setLanguage($language);
        $description->setDescription($d);
        $word->setDescrp($description);

        $this->em->persist($word);
        $this->em->flush();
```

The language is chosen by a drop-down-list. This code of course spits that the language already exists in the database. How do I simply get the ID of the language and put it as a FK language_id in the 'word' table in the database, through Doctrine code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is not visible from your code where you grab the language ID. I can see that you grab description and wordname but for language you only use a new instance of language and add that empty instance to the word. Are you sending a language ID through the form submit?

Comment: I am sorry, I obviously have missed the part of populating the language object. You can have a look again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well today i finally solved it... the solution is so simple I was completely blind. I was obviously not thinking properly about the functionality of Doctrine.

First I tried this:

```
    $this->em->getConnection()->executeQuery("Update word set language_id = ? where word = ?", array($this->langIds[$wordlan], $w));
```

in order to set existing language to the word, however that's not a proper solution since it defeats the purpose of using ORM. Today, the light bulb just went off and I figured out, that since doctrine keeps connection between the objects you obtain and the DB. For instance:

```
    $word_check = $this->em->getRepository('Entity\Word')->findOneBy(array('word' => $w));
```

Gives me back a word 'where word = $w'. If I simply modify this word and call $em->flush(); it will save the differences in the database. So I simply figured that if I obtain the required language object and add it to the new word, and than call $em->flush(); it should create the connection in the DB via the FKs between the existing language and the new word, instead of creating a new object of language and adding it to the word. Although this new object has the same id and string word, it treats it as a new objects and doctrine tries to save it into the language table as a new entry, therefore it spits out an exception because of the constraints of 'unique language' I have set. So this piece of code simply works:

```
    $new_w = new Entity\Word;

            $new_w->setWord($w);

            $lang = $this->em->getRepository('Entity\Language')->findOneBy(array('language' => $selected_language));

            $new_w->setLanguage($lang);                                

            $this->em->flush();
```

So this simply adds an existing language to the newly creating word and sets the FKs correctly. I am sorry if it was hard for you to understand what I was looking for in this post, however I hope that since it is solved now, someone may find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is very important to know what are you posting with your form:

```
$desclan = $this->input->post('desclan'); //language is selected from a drop down 
                                              //list populated from the DB
```

You say here that the language is selected from a drop down list and populated from the DB, now I ask you what is being posted with the form? A drop down list will probably post an ID of the language that already exist in the database. 
You just need to find the correct language:

```
$languageFind = $entityManager->find('Entity\Language', $lanId); // $lanId is posted via form
```

Then add the language to the word:

```
$word->setLanguage($languageFind);
```

P.S: The error "language already exists" is because of this:

```
$language->setLanguageId($lanId); // assuming that $lanId is obtained from DB
```

You cant setLanguageId() of the new Language class instance with the $lanId that already exists in the database.

Comment: All you have said makes sense, besides the fact that I have already tried everything possible. The drop down list returns the language itself. First i have tried to simply just set the language "name" ( the string as you wish) without setting the ID of the language, since the ID is a PK and it is auto incremented. The "entry already exists" is caused because I have set the language to be unique. Thus, an entry with the same language is impossible. Therefore I need a simplest possible way ( besides executing raw SQL query ) to do smth like w.language_id = l.id where l.language = 'English';

Comment: If the dropdownlist returns the language itself(I presume you mean the whole language object) then you must  $word->setLanguage($languageObject->getId());
The unique language means that the language name is unique in the languages table, here in this code you must add a language ID inside the word table, column language_id